# Debugging Doctrine huge memory consumption

Tags: symfony, doctrine

getting out of memory with doctrine within Symfony, but it's just like 20 rows with pagination.. How do I start debugging this?

[image]

Comment: Depends on the Entity models and the executed query, along with the resulting services in your controller. 20 Rows w/ Pagination may be off, if your query is populating every single row on the backend without a limit. Please post the code in your controller, with its related service processes that your using and the Queries doctrine is executing.

Comment: @brgs, If you use pagination (probably Pagerfanta or KNP), try to limit results per page to exactly 1 and inspect again in debug-bar.

Comment: Oh yeah, got this one resolved, so this had nothing to do with the page results, but one of the filter input results which required group by. Started by commenting out the twig contents and eventually found the cause.